# How to convert RDD list to RDD row in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', ])

# convert to as follows
..., ...
..., ...

# show result
rdd.collect()
[Row(col='a1'), Row(col='a2'), Row(col='a3'), Row(col='a4'), Row(col='a5'), ]
```

I know in `Java Spark` we can use `Row` but not implemented in `PySpark`.
So what is the most suitable way to implement it? Convert it to `dict` then convert it `rdd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then import `Row` package.

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', ])
from pyspark.sql import Row 

rdd.map(lambda x: Row(x)).collect()

[<Row('a1')>, <Row('a2')>, <Row('a3')>, <Row('a4')>, <Row('a5')>]
```